# .net C# Spliting xml file

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am using a code from Code Project to split an xml file into multiple files. It is working fine in this below case: "Registrations" is the parent node and when split is among "Registration"

```
<Registrations>
<Registration xmlns:i="...............">
  <RegistrationID>108260</RegistrationID>
...................
..................
 </Registration>
 <Registration xmlns:i="...............">
  <RegistrationID>108260</RegistrationID>
   ...................
   ..................
 </Registration>
 <Registration xmlns:i="...............">
  <RegistrationID>108260</RegistrationID>
   ...................
   ..................
 </Registration>
```

But the code is not working when XML file is in this format: "RegistrationOpenData" is the root node, then there is another node "Registrations" and split has to be made among "Registration"

```
<RegistrationOpenData xmlns:i="............" xmlns="">
<Description>......</Description>
<InformationURL>..........</InformationURL>
<SourceAgency>...............</SourceAgency>
<SourceSystem>...........</SourceSystem>
<StartDate>................</StartDate>
<EndDate i:nil="true" />
<Registrations>
<Registration xmlns:i="...............">
  <RegistrationID>108260</RegistrationID>
...................
..................
 </Registration>
 <Registration xmlns:i="...............">
  <RegistrationID>108260</RegistrationID>
...................
..................
 </Registration>
 <Registration xmlns:i="...............">
  <RegistrationID>108260</RegistrationID>
...................
..................
 </Registration>
</Registrations>
</RegistrationOpenData>
```

The code that I am using is as below:

```cs
private void buttonSPLIT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sourceFile = @"D:\sample.xml";
    string rootElement = "RegistrationOpenData";
    string descElement = "Registration";
    int take = 1;
    string destFilePrefix = "RegistrationsPart";
    string destPath = @"D:\PART\";

    SplitXmlFile(sourceFile, rootElement, descElement, take,
        destFilePrefix, destPath);

}

private static void SplitXmlFile(string sourceFile
                    , string rootElement
                    , string descendantElement
                    , int takeElements
                    , string destFilePrefix
                    , string destPath)
{          
    XElement xml = XElement.Load(sourceFile);
    // Child elements from source file to split by.
    var childNodes = xml.Descendants(descendantElement);

    // This is the total number of elements to be sliced up into 
    // separate files.
    int cnt = childNodes.Count();

    var skip = 0;
    var take = takeElements;
    var fileno = 0;

    // Split elements into chunks and save to disk.
    while (skip < cnt)
    {
        // Extract portion of the xml elements.
        var c1 = childNodes.Skip(skip)
                        .Take(take);

        // Setup number of elements to skip on next iteration.
        skip += take;
        // File sequence no for split file.
        fileno += 1;
        // Filename for split file.
        var filename = String.Format(destFilePrefix + "_{0}.xml", fileno);
        // Create a partial xml document.
        XElement frag = new XElement(rootElement, c1);
        // Save to disk.
        frag.Save(destPath + filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: `XElement.Descendants` is recursive in its results. I think you might actually be looking for `XElement.Elements`

Comment: I tried using var childNodes = xml.Elements("Registration"); instead of var childNodes = xml.Descendants(descendantElement); but it is still not working. Giving no results.

Comment: Can you show what output you are expecting to achieve?

Comment: The first format that I have specified in this question is the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested your code in VS 2015 and it seems to work. It generates 3 XML files with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RegistrationOpenData>
  <Registration>
    <RegistrationID>108260</RegistrationID>
  </Registration>
</RegistrationOpenData>
```

Is it what you are expecting ? Can you give more details on your issue ?

Comment: I am using VS 2012. The first format that I have specified in this question is the expected output. If from the XML file Parent Node "RegistrationOpenData" is removed then the code is working fine and file is getting splitted. But if both "RegistrationOpenData" and "Registrations" is present nothing happens. No errors, no split.

Answer (score 0):

as a quick solution (i assume you do not want to make changes in your codeproject script) you can add this line:

```
private static void SplitXmlFile(string sourceFile
                    , string rootElement
                    , string descendantElement
                    , int takeElements
                    , string destFilePrefix
                    , string destPath)
{ 
    XElement xml = XElement.Load(sourceFile);
    XNamespace ns = "http://services.hpd.gov"; // This line must be added.
    xml = xml.Element(ns + rootElement); // rootElement must be "Registrations". And also this line must be added.
    // Child elements from source file to split by.
    var childNodes = xml.Descendants(ns + descendantElement);
.....
.....
```

here is working sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6sOOdH

Comment: I tried this modification but still not working. I am using VS2012. I hope this is not the case.

Comment: In my case the code childNodes.Count() is returning 0 hence it is not even entering the while loop.

Comment: hi, i tried it in fiddle and it's entering to loop.https://dotnetfiddle.net/6sOOdH

Comment: I just checked in the fiddle and its working fine. I would like to know is this the right way of passing xml file through a path and not string value as follows: xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(@"D:\sample.xml")); I am getting the following error on using this line of code in the fiddle link you just provided: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: This is the link for sample.xml file: http://www.prminfotech.com/sample.xml

Comment: Because of your sample xml has single Registrations node. it must have more than one for splitting i think.

Comment: I have mentioned previously that split has to be made among "Registration". The xml tree is this way RegistrationOpenData-->Registrations-->Registration. Split has to be made among Registration and not Registrations. If I remove RegistrationOpenData from the XML file split is working fine but if all the 3 nodes are present split is not working.

Comment: ok i've got it. Because of your namespace. i've changed my answer.